# Is it safe to use Tails with 3g connection via Android USB?

Tags: tails, android, mobile

I'm running Tails OS with USB stick. I've BCM43227 WiFi card therefore I'm unable to use WiFi with Tails. The option is to use my cellphone's USB internet connection while it's connecting through 3G. Is it safe? I mean, Android devices have some more identifiers like SIM id, IMEI...

Another option is to setup wl module within Tails, but I really can't figure out a way to do it ([this](https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/#index20h2) might help).

Answer (score 1):

It is equally (un)safe as using your wired home internet connection.
Both are registered to you and the respective providers can see your data, which is encrypted.

Your IMEI and SIM are only used to connect to the cellular network. Not for IP streams over this connection.

Comment: the EFF provides a really good [site to see which people will notice what, while you are using tor (or not)](https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https)! -- **in short:** if you use tor right your ISP (whether mobile or wired) will just see, that you are connecting to the tor-network.